# Understandind the code javascript

Tags: javascript

I am here again to get help understanding this code the function is called without any parameter

```
var d= $_GET();
```

how can this happen? Why regexp return three values because we have m, key value?
What is the purpose of if(param) and create an param key in object?
Please tell me if is any chat where I can get quick help not posting every question I have there.

```
function $_GET(param) {
    var vars = {};
    window.location.href.replace( 
        /[?&]+([^=&]+)=?([^&]*)?/gi, // regexp
        function( m, key, value ) { // callback
            vars[key] = value !== undefined ? value : '';
        }
    );

    if ( param ) {
        return vars[param] ? vars[param] : null;    
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Comment: But have you  any solution?

Comment: very surprised  having two down votes. at least provide a solution like the one below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can this happen?

Because in JavaScript, it doesn't matter how many arguments a function declares, it can be called with more than that, or fewer. If it declares an argument and you call it without giving that argument, inside the function value of the argument will be `undefined` (which is a specific, real value arguments and variables and properties can have).

> Why regexp return three values because we have m, key value?

The regex includes two capture groups (the parts in `()`). The way `String#replace` is defined when using a regular expression and a callback function is that it will call the function with **all** the text that matched the expression as a whole as the first argument (`m`, probably for "match") and then with additional arguments containing the text that matched the capture groups. Simpler example:

```
"testing".replace(/te(..)(...)/, function(m, c0, c1) {
    // m  = "testing"
    // c0 = "st", the characters that matched the first capture group
    // c1 = "ing", the characters that matched the second capture group
});
```

> What is the purpose of if(param) and create an param key in object?

`if (param)` tests to see if the `param` argument's value is *truthy*. In JavaScript, values that coerce to `true` when used as booleans are called *truthy* (and ones that coerce to `false` are *falsey*). The falsey values are `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`, and of course, `false`. So `if (param)` checks to see if `param` contains a value that **isn't** one of those.

If `param` is truthy, the code assumes it's a string (or something that can coerce to string) and returns the property from `vars` that has that name, if there is one and it's truthy; otherwise it returns `null`.

If `param` is falsey (as it will be when you call `$_GET` with no param at all, since `undefined` is falsey), it just returns `vars`.

Basically, `_GET` is used to parse query string parameters and either return an object with all of them, or return the specific one named by passing in `param`.

Comment: so we can use param just as an id or am i completely wrong? I do not understand the point

Comment: @EduardHasanaj: What do you mean by "just as an id"?

Comment: @EduardHasanaj: In `vars[param]`, `param` is being used to look up a property. In JavaScript, you can access properties in two ways: Using an identifier with literal notation and a dot (`obj.foo`), and using a string with brackets notation (`obj["foo"]`). In brackets notation, the string can be the resutl of any expression, including a variable lookup. So `obj.foo`, `obj["foo"]`, and `var x ="f";` then `obj[x + "o" + o"]` all access the `foo` property of `obj`. That's what's happening with `vars[param]`.

Comment: But why we need this to identify something?

Comment: @EduardHasanaj: The function is designed to do one of two things: Return all the query parameters (if you don't give it a param), or return just one of them (if you do).